# phpmyadmin why only show the menu elements?

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

**Server:** Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
**php:** 8.0.16
**phpmyadmin:** latest with apt
**The problem:**

If I hit refresh, I can see the database list just for a second.
I tried with different browser, cleared cookies, and history.

[image]

Comment: Well that's very unusual. Are there any hints in the webserver error log?

Comment: Could you also please check the actual phpMAdmin version, perhaps with `dpkg -l phpmyadmin`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Problem is that you need to have phpmyadmin version 5 for php8. You need to upgrade it manually:
Here is what helped me:
https://devanswers.co/manually-upgrade-phpmyadmin/