# Phpmyadmin menu items are not visible. What would be the reason?

Tags: php, nginx, server, phpmyadmin

I installed my Laravel application on digitalocean with *LEMP* stack. Afterwards, I followed the instructions for phpmyadmin installation, but when I log in to phpmyadmin, the menu elements disappear **2-3 seconds** after the page is loaded and the panel does not work properly. I leave the sample image below. How can I resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Can you inspect elements at menu position? Probably, its blocked by some browser extestion

Comment: @Vlad Salabun I also tried chrome, safari or opera browsers but I can't view it. From the Inspect section, I see that the menu items appear when the page is loaded, and then suddenly disappear.

Comment: I had the same issue. You can find my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71239874/phpmyadmin-why-only-show-the-menu-elements/71983226#71983226

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to PHP 8 need Phpmyadmin version 5. You can fix the problem by doing a manual upgrade. https://devanswers.co/manually-upgrade-phpmyadmin/